# Cakephp Custom Validation Method Returning False but Saves and Displays no Message

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have the following validator under ValidationDefault to check whether the effective_until date is after the effective_on date. If false it should display the message.

```
$validator
            ->add('effective_until', 'custom', ['rule' => 'checkEffectiveDateRange', 'provider' => 'table', 'message' => 'The effective until date must come after the effective on date.']);
```

I have the following custom function in the same table but even when I purposely set the effective_until date to be earlier than the effective_on date it saves the data and doesn't display the validation error message. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
    public function checkEffectiveDateRange($check, $context)
    {
        if(array_key_exists('newRecord',$context))
        {
                return strtotime($context['data']['effective_on']) < strtotime($check);
        }
        else
        {
                return strtotime($context['effective_on']) < strtotime($check);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not enough data to provide an answer here, but consider using an anonymous function for your validation method:
`
$validator
    ->add('effective_until', 'custom', [
        'on' => 'create',
        'rule' => function ($check, $context) {
            if(array_key_exists...) {
                return strtotime... < strtotime...
            }
            return strtotime... < ...
        },
        'message' => __('Validation message...')
    ]);
`

Comment: What additional data is needed so I can provide? Is the anonymous function the only option? In version 3 this was working with my table function but now it seems like it doesn't recognize any of the table functions I use for validation. This is one of 3 and none of them are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that may need this I resolved this by changing the validator to below

**Validator**

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator): Validator
{
        $validator
            ->add('effective_until', 'custom',
            ['rule' => function($check, $context) {
                if($this->checkEffectiveDateRange($check, $context)) {
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            },
            'message' => 'The effective until date must come after the effective on date.']);

        return $validator;
}
```